# Flutter: Redirect to another page from widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am trying to implement a logout page. So when the user clicks on logout button in the navigation following code is called:

```
Class Logout extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      final provider = Provider.of<SignInProvider>(context, listen: true);
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () async {
         provider.isLoggedIn = false;
         provider.notifyListeners();
         Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginGate()));
      });
       return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
   }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
The following assertion was thrown building MainScreen(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<SelectedIndex?>, _InheritedProviderScope<SignInProvider?>], state: _MainScreenState#6a8ce):
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

I tried adding the delay hoping that would fix the issue but didn't help. Would appreciate some help on how to handle this.

Logout Button is shown using NavigationRail

```
const NavigationRailDestination(
  icon: Icon(Icons.logout),
  label: Text('Logout'),
),
```

And the Logout widget is called using following:

```
child: Row(
   children: [
     NavigationRailExample(),
     const VerticalDivider(thickness: 1, width: 1),
     Expanded(
        child: screenSwitch[providerSelectedIndex.selectedIndex],
     )
   ],
 ),
List<Widget> screenSwitch = [
   HomeScreen(),
   Screen1(),
   Screen2(),
   Screen3(),
   Screen4(),
   Screen5(),
   Screen6(),
   Logout(),
];
```

Comment: Logout class is your button class? if not could you include that too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling your async function in build method which is wrong. Try this:

```
class Logout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: doLogOut(context),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> doLogOut(BuildContext context) async {
    final provider = Provider.of<SignInProvider>(context, listen: true);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () async {
      provider.isLoggedIn = false;
      provider.notifyListeners();
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginGate()));
    });
  }
}
```